# Oracle analytic function window defined by data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i, analytic-functions

I have a table which represents a line-by-line dump of the data read from a particular text file format. Each line may represent a "master" or a "detail" line, indicated via `rec_type` code. I'd like to write a query that gets the "master" lines alongside the associated detail lines. I've come up with something that does the job, but it seems a bit hackish and am interested in better ways if any.

```
CREATE TABLE mdtest
 (rec_seq  NUMBER        PRIMARY KEY
 ,rec_type VARCHAR2(3)   NOT NULL
 ,rec_data VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO mdtest VALUES (1, '100', 'Bill Jones');
INSERT INTO mdtest VALUES (2, '200', '20080115,100.25');
INSERT INTO mdtest VALUES (3, '100', 'John Smith');
INSERT INTO mdtest VALUES (4, '200', '20090701,80.95');
INSERT INTO mdtest VALUES (5, '200', '20091231,110.35');
```

Desired Result:

```
SEQ_EMP  EMP_NAME    SEQ_DATA  EMP_DATA
=======  ==========  ========  ===============
      1  Bill Jones         2  20080115,100.25
      3  John Smith         4  20090701,80.95
      3  John Smith         5  20091231,110.35
```

Assumptions:

- records are processed in sequence of rec_seq
- first record type is a "`100`"
- each "`100`" record has 1 or more "`200`" records following

Note: this is for Oracle 9i, however we should be upgrading to 11g R1 this year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT seq_emp 
      ,SUBSTR(emp_seq_name,10) emp_name 
      ,seq_data 
      ,emp_data 
FROM  (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN rec_type = '100' THEN rec_seq END) 
              OVER (ORDER BY rec_seq 
                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                             AND CURRENT ROW) seq_emp 
             ,MAX(CASE 
                  WHEN rec_type = '100' 
                  THEN TO_CHAR(rec_seq,'fm00000000') || '|' || rec_data 
                  END) 
              OVER (ORDER BY rec_seq 
                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                             AND CURRENT ROW) emp_seq_name 
             ,rec_seq seq_data 
             ,rec_type 
             ,rec_data emp_data 
       FROM   mdtest) 
WHERE  rec_type = '200' 
ORDER BY seq_data;
```

As you can see, I'm using the MAX reporting analytic function with a window starting from the top of the set down to the current row, to get the relevant "100" record for the current "200" record; then in the outer query I'm discarding the unneeded "100" records.

To get emp_name, I've had to append the rec_seq with the data so that the MAX function still picks the correct header record; then in the outer query I chop the rec_seq off.

I've played with other analytic functions and syntax including FIRST_VALUE and the KEEP syntax, but neither of these seem to make this job simpler; the difficulty is that the window is defined by the value of rec_type instead of being some constant offset.

Comment: @Jeffrey: you're making a single pass on the data, you won't be able to query this more efficiently. As you probably know the model is "hackish" (master and detail in the same table) and consequently all queries on such a model will look weird :)

Answer (score 1):

In a desire for simplicity, do you think it's worth loading each record type into a separate import table before processing?

```
create table mdtest100 as select * from mdtest where rec_type = 100;

create table mdtest200 as select * from mdtest where rec_type = 200;

with mdtest_detail as
    (
    select
        (select max(m.rec_seq) from mdtest100 m 
         where m.rec_seq < r200.rec_seq) master_rec_seq,
        r200.* 
    from 
        mdtest200 r200
    )
select
    m.rec_seq seq_emp,
    m.rec_data emp_name,
    d.rec_seq seq_data,
    d.rec_data emp_data
from
    mdtest_detail d
        inner join mdtest100 m on m.rec_seq = d.master_rec_seq
order by
    seq_emp,
    seq_data;


    SEQ_EMP  EMP_NAME    SEQ_DATA   EMP_DATA          
    1        Bill Jones  2          20080115,100.25          
    3        John Smith  4          20090701,80.95          
    3        John Smith  5          20091231,110.35
```

This might lend itself to a more maintainable solution and will let you parse out and validate the comm-separated EMP_DATA field separately.

Just a thought - sorry if you're only looking for an Analytics solution.

Comment: that's ok - probably a good idea to point out that the table is not designed for this kind of query; it's just a log of import activity.